# Return random rows from `SELECT` in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

How can I select random rows from a SQL table using CockroachDB? For example, if I have a number of questions and I want to generate a different sequence each time a student loads them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CockroachDB doesn't offer an efficient way to do this yet! For a non-efficient way you can use `SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;`

Alternatively, you can handle shuffling the results of a `SELECT` statement in your application itself. After putting the results into an array (or any other aggregate-like structure), you can also shuffle the order there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following statement to select random number of rows from cockroach db.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE round(random()*10) % 10 = 0 LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more efficient way you can add an integer column `randomid` to each row. When inserting put a random number in that column. Then you can retrieve a random column with:

`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE randomid >= ? ORDER BY randomid LIMIT 1;`

where ? is a random number.

Note that you will need extra storage for the random number and you must index the `randomid` column.

Also note that you may need to run this query twice (>= and <) to ensure you get a result. Though the probability of striking out on the first query shoud be very low.